# Display data from json with discord.py

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, bots

I'm currently making a discord bot that will display osu! stats. This is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def osu(osu_name : str):
    """Adds two numbers together."""
    await bot.say("Fetching data")
    url = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?k={ my api key }&u=' + osu_name
    # Do the HTTP get request
    response = requests.get(url, verify=True) #Verify is check SSL certificate
    # Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data
    await bot.say(response.json())
```

The osu! api gives this in its json:

```
[{
    "user_id"      : "1",
    "username"     : "User name",
    "count300"     : "1337",      // Total amount for all ranked and approved beatmaps played
    "count100"     : "123",       // Total amount for all ranked and approved beatmaps played
    "count50"      : "69",        // Total amount for all ranked and approved beatmaps played
    "playcount"    : "42",        // Only counts ranked and approved beatmaps
    "ranked_score" : "666666",    // Counts the best individual score on each ranked and approved beatmaps
    "total_score"  : "999999998", // Counts every score on ranked and approved beatmaps
    "pp_rank"      : "2442",
    "level"        : "50.5050",
    "pp_raw"       : "3113",
    "accuracy"     : "98.1234",
    "count_rank_ss": "54",
    "count_rank_s" : "81",        // Counts for SS/S/A ranks on maps
    "count_rank_a" : "862",    
    "country"      : "DE",        // Uses the ISO3166-1 alpha-2 country code naming. See this for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)
    "pp_country_rank":"1337",     // The user's rank in the country.
    "events"       : [{           // Contains events for this user
        "display_html"  : "<img src='\/images\/A_small.png'\/>...",
        "beatmap_id"    : "222342",
        "beatmapset_id" : "54851",
        "date"      : "2013-07-07 22:34:04",
        "epicfactor"    : "1"      // How "epic" this event is (between 1 and 32)
    }, { ... }, ...]
}]
```

My code it displays it like this in discord

[image: discord screenshot]

I would like to only show a few of the things from the json, such as the "pp_raw", "level", "accuracy", etc.

Comment: Okay, so only print part of the JSON. You can access it the same way you would access any other dictionary.

Comment: That is not quite accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's builtin `json` module to convert the json response into a python dictionary - just `import json` and then do something like this to access individual elements of the response: `data = json.loads(response.json())[0]`. Then you can access individual elements like `data['pp_raw']` and display them as you see fit.

Comment: could you give a snippet for the whole thing i just tried it and it didn't work

Comment: it did not display the data when i added     ``data = json.loads(response.json())
    await bot.say(data['pp_raw'])``

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the response was a list. editing now.

Answer (score 1):

The `data = response.json()` returns a **list** of dictionary objects.  So you have to specify the index first before accessing the value.  Suppose you want to access the `pp_raw` in the first object, it will look like:

```
print data[0]['pp_raw']
```