# I cant get this jsons tring to print the data thats in it

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

So im making this Discord bot and one of the commands is to add api names and what comes with the api and so that command works and the code looks like this:

```py
#Add a Method to the json string command
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Reseller')
async def addmethod(ctx,api, method):
    methods = await get_method_data()
    methods[str(api)] = {}
    methods[str(api)]['Method'] = method
    methods[str(api)]['api'] = api
    with open("methods.json", "w") as output: 
        json.dump(methods,output)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{method} has been added to list', color=0x000000)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Then im making another command where it grabs all the data from the json file and prints it into the Discord chat but its not making the data that i inputted print into the Discord chat here is the code of the ERROR

```py
@bot.command()
async def methodss(ctx):
    methods = await get_method_data()
    method =  methods['Method']
    apiname = methods['api']
    em = discord.Embed(title = "B")  
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet Balance", value = method)
    em.add_field(name = "Bank balance", value = apiname)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Where did I go wrong??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I tried to fix your code formatting. I'm not sure if the formatting help makes this clear, but the `\`\`\`` that you use before and after the code have to be on separate lines. (You can give the name of the language you are using on the opening backtick line, to tell the syntax highlighter what to highlight.)

Comment: `methods['Method']` seeing how you added the api name, I don't think that the field `Method` is at root level..

Comment: "Then im making another command where it grabs all the data from the json file and prints it into the Discord chat " Well, *does* it actually grab that data? You haven't shown us `get_method_data`. You also haven't actually shown us *what happens when you try this code*. If there is an error message, you should [show that in full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) - copied and pasted, starting from the `Traceback (most recent call last):` line, formatted as code. Otherwise, if the output is wrong, show exact actual vs. expected output.

Comment: Is this useful to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231937/display-data-from-json-with-discord-py